# Grails 3.2 - Disconnect from database and reconnect

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm running some functional tests where I restore the database to a clean state in between tests. Unfortunately the restore command for SQL Server requires there be no other connections to the database. Is there a way I can call some test code to disconnect Grails/GORM and then reconnect once the database restore has completed?

Comment: The clean up sounds brutal, can you either truncate the tables or delete data from them instead?

Comment: I resolved the issue. Answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the database restore code bring the database offline, do the restore, then bring the database back online.

Adding

```
    properties:
        testOnBorrow: true
        testWhileIdle: true
        testOnReturn: false
        validationQuery: SELECT 1
```

to the database setup fixed the issue by having the database reconnect automatically.

Comment: I tried same but I have to restart my application on SQL Server restart

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49027576/grails-3-automatic-reconnect-with-ms-sql-server